# How to populate a vector with an own function in R

Tags: r, apply

I have a vector with some information and I need to create a new one that contains the log variation without using a loop for better performance, my data looks like this:

```
Var1
12
34
23
56
9
10
```

I am already try using sapply

```
sapply(Var1, function(i) {
  log(Var[i]/Var[i-1])
})
```

But it doesn't work for me, I want something like this

```
Var1     New_VaR2
12  NA
34  1.041453875
23  -0.390866309
59  0.942043228
9   -1.880312867
10  0.105360516
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `x$Var2 <- c(NA, log(x$Var1[-1] / x$Var1[-nrow(x)]))`, no `for` or `sapply` needed, as `log` is naturally vectorized. The need for `NA` is because the operation you're doing decreases the length of the return vector by one, so if you want to add it to the original frame, you need to make sure it is the same length.

Comment: FYI: with your `sapply` code, realize that `i` is the *value* of each of `Var1`, but internally you are treating it as an *index* on that vector. You might have been able to do something like: `sapply(seq_along(x$Var1)[-1], function(i) log(x$Var1[i]/x$Var1[i-1]))`, though for reasons stated in the previous answer, you'll need to prepend an `NA`. (And the vectorized use of `log` is much faster than `sapply` or `for` loops, use vectorized funcs whenever possible/available.)

Comment: Thank you guys, you are amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ***much*** prefer the solution in bullet 1, but a correction to your code is offered in bullet 2 for your reference. (Please use 1. :-)

1. Many of R's functions are vectorized by default, meaning they happily work on 1 value, or 2 values, or 2 million values. One benefit of doing this is that you don't need to explicitly try to loop or iterate, so simpler code. Another benefit is that when a function is natively vectorized, it is typically (but not always) much faster than iterating manually.

   ```r
   x$Var2 <- c(NA, log(x$Var1[-1] / x$Var1[-nrow(x)]))
   x
   #   Var1       Var2
   # 1   12         NA
   # 2   34  1.0414539
   # 3   23 -0.3908663
   # 4   56  0.8898575
   # 5    9 -1.8281271
   # 6   10  0.1053605
   ```
2. In your `sapply` code, you are assign each *value* of `Var1` to `i`, but treating it internally as an *index*. So the first time the `log` is attempted, `i` is 12, but `Var1[i]` is not what you mean it to be, even if your vector were long enough for it to be correct. For this, you should likely iterate over a sequence that starts at 2, such as `seq_along(Var1)[-1]` (which is *always* safer than `2:length(Var1)`).

   ```r
   x$Var3 <- c(NA, sapply(seq_along(x$Var1)[-1], function(i) log(x$Var1[i]/x$Var1[i-1])))
   x
   #   Var1       Var2       Var3
   # 1   12         NA         NA
   # 2   34  1.0414539  1.0414539
   # 3   23 -0.3908663 -0.3908663
   # 4   56  0.8898575  0.8898575
   # 5    9 -1.8281271 -1.8281271
   # 6   10  0.1053605  0.1053605
   ```

---

Data:

```r
x <- structure(list(Var1 = c(12L, 34L, 23L, 56L, 9L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most straightforward way of doing this in R is with `dplyr::lag`.

```
log(df1$Var1/dplyr::lag(df1$Var1))
#[1]         NA  1.0414539 -0.3908663  0.9420432 -1.8803129  0.1053605

all.equal(df1$New_VaR2, log(df1$Var1/dplyr::lag(df1$Var1)))
#[1] TRUE
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Var1     New_VaR2
12  NA
34  1.041453875
23  -0.390866309
59  0.942043228
9   -1.880312867
10  0.105360516
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: You have package-bloat ... the `lag` you're using here is `dplyr::lag`, not `stats::lag`. If you try it without loading `dplyr` (`log(df1$Var1/stats::lag(df1$Var1))`), you'll get all zeroes. (This is one reason I tend to be explicit, unfortunately, since I've been similarly burned several times.)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, didn't notice it. That's a well known conflict.

Comment: I don't know what I find more annoying: the fact that `stats::lag` does not do what I expect (for most of my uses), or that `dplyr` and friends conflict with many base functions, significantly redefining the output. (Several are better, I believe, but not all.)